# form ajax forget's changes made in previous ajax callback calls

Tags: forms, ajax

Why do changes don't get saved in `$form`, or what is it that's overriding it?

I would like to set custom class to multiple fieldsets in an ajax callback function:

```
if (something) {
  $form['fieldset_01']['#attributes'] = array('class' => array('custom_class'));
  $form['fieldset_02']['#attributes'] = array('class' => array('custom_class'));
}
elseif (somethingelse) {
  $form['fieldset_11']['#attributes'] = array('class' => array('custom_class'));
  $form['fieldset_12']['#attributes'] = array('class' => array('custom_class'));
} 

return $form;
```

When `$form` is returned, the element that I have set in this call is rendered fine, with a new CSS class but the elements I have rendered in previous calls have lost this new class, as if they were rendered with default values.

EDIT: my form creation function

```
function mynode_form($form, &$form_state) {

$nid = $form_state['values']['nid'];

$ajax = array(
'callback' => 'mynode_ajax',
'wrapper' => 'mynode_form',        
'event' => 'change',
'method' => 'replace',
);

$node = node_load($nid);
$title = $node->field_title['und'][0]['value'];              

$form = array();
$form['#prefix'] = '<div id="mynode_form">';
$form['#suffix'] = '</div>';

$form['nid'] = array(
  '#value' => $nid,
  '#type' => 'hidden',
);

$form['fieldset_0'] = array(
  '#type' => 'fieldset',
  '#collapsible' => true,    
  '#title' => 'Fieldset title 0',      
  //'#attributes' => array('class' => array('a', 'b')),
  '#weight' => 1,
);

$form['fieldset_0']['textfield_0'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => t('Title 0?'),        
  '#ajax' => $ajax,    
);

$form['fieldset_1'] = array(
  '#type' => 'fieldset',
  '#collapsible' => true,    
  '#title' => 'Fieldset title 1',      
  //'#attributes' => array('class' => array('a', 'b')),
  '#weight' => 1,
);

$form['fieldset_1']['textfield_1'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => t('Title 1?'),        
  '#ajax' => $ajax,    
);

if (isset($form_state['triggering_element']['#name'])){
  $key = $form_state['triggering_element']['#name'];
  switch($key){
    case 'textfield_0':            
      $form['fieldset_0']['#attributes'] = array('class' => array('a', 'b',   'c'));                                    
      $form['fieldset_1']['#attributes'] = array('class' => array('a',   'b'));
    break;    
  }
}
else{
  //only the first time
  $form['fieldset_0']['#attributes'] = array('class' => array('a', 'b'));
  $form['fieldset_1']['#attributes'] = array('class' => array('a', 'b'));
}     
return $form;
}
```

Comment: There's syntax errors in this code.

Comment: I must have done something, while indenting.. i think it is fixed now.

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with that code. I hope you're clearing all cache after you change your functions as form arrays sometimes may get cached. Also I'd wrap anything referencing `$form_state` inside an `isset()` check to avoid warnings and notices.

Answer (score 3):

AJAX callback function is meant to only tell Drupal what to update. By design all you do in it is for one call only.

Permanent changes needs to be done in main form creation function. I usually see them done in block like that:

```
if (!empty($form_state['values'])) {
  //here you are supposed to use these values
}
```

Comment: I have checked this, but i couldn't find the style changes - class values for certain element. How can i check this? It is not a value..

Comment: You need to alter $form array, not $form_state. You need $form_state only to know that ajax was actually called and what element triggered your form building function.

Comment: I get form with print drupal_render(drupal_get_form($form_name, $request_id)); and it seems that function for creating that form si getting called only the first time.

Comment: Your form function is called everytime before an ajax callback is called. So the condition and the modification of `$form` should be inside your form function.

Comment: Is there any reason why it wouldn't be called? I set a breakpoint and it was reached only the first time, when form is initially created.

Comment: @gregab are you sure your debugger is actually connected to calls invoked by AJAX? they happen in separate processes, you know.

Comment: @Molot I am pretty sure. In the same debug session i reach form_name_form function and in ajax call i reach ajax callback function but not form_name_form function.

Comment: To test that the form is being rebuilt, a more hands-on approach would be to use the devel module and put `dpm('Form rebuilt');` at the top of the form function. This will output a message to the message area everytime the function runs. With Ajax calls however, if you're not writing anything to the screen you should open another tab with a different page, and after you trigger the ajax call, switch to the other tab and refresh the page to see the message being output. But thing is, the main problem is your condition and form modification is in callback, should be in form builder.

Comment: i moved everything in function which creates form and now nothing is changed when ajax callback returns $form.

Comment: Can you update your question with the current code?

Comment: i have updated with code